# Limit Service Methods to particular time of day

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 2 long running service methods that I want to limit to a certain period during the day. Mainly outside business hours. These service methods are part of a larger contract that contains methods that I do want available during all hours. What would be the best way to limit the 2 methods without changing the overall contract. Would Application_BeginRequest be the place to start? Would returning a 503 service unavailable be appropriate here? How can I detect the method being requested?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use begin request  you  can use just [MessageInspector in WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx) 
and Try  to  intercept all actions and respond with  the status code you  want 
All what you need is to follow this steps

**1-step**

In your code you should add a MessageInspectorExtension

```
 class MessageInspectorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(MessageInspector); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new MessageInspector();
        }
    }
```

`MessageInspector` will do all the work you need and it should be defined like this

```
//here the `MessageInspector` class showing what are the interfaces responsable for doing this  
public class MessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior, IEndpointBehavior
    {
    }
```

The mains methods you need are

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
              //here you can add your logic to check  hour and time 
              // 
          return null;  
        }

Which is called after an inbound message has been received but before the message is dispatched to the intended operation
```

**and**

public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
 if (!reply.IsFault) return;

```
    if (!reply.Headers.Action.StartsWith("your actin here", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return;
    //get the string value for desired response code
    string statusCodeString = reply.Headers.Action.Substring(17);
    //convert to int
    int statusCodeInt;
    if (!int.TryParse(statusCodeString, out statusCodeInt)) return;

    //cast to HttpStatusCode
    System.Net.HttpStatusCode statusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
    try
    {
        statusCode = (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)statusCodeInt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Here the response code is changed
    reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() { StatusCode = statusCode };
}
```

}
           }
    wich is called after the operation  has returned but before the reply message is sent

**2-step**

In your app config you have to add a behavior definition like the following

```
    <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>           
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorWithInterceptor">
              <ServiceInspector/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        <behaviors>
<!--Extensions-->   
     <extensions>
          <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="ServiceInspector" type="yourNameSpace.MessageInspector.MessageInspectorExtension, assemblyname, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
```

**"3-step**

```
<service name="yourServiceContractFullName" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorWithInterceptor">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://yourserver:port/root/yourServiceContract" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBindingConfig" contract="YourContract" />
      </service>
```